# Struggling with inheritance and prototyping in JavaScript - prototyped methods don't work like "should"

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, prototype

I've got small test exercise to do, made by my potential employer.
Here's [CODE](http://pastebin.com/zSXfz4C1) I made.

Employer's assumptions:
Circle, Window and Rectangle classes should inherit from some superclass - which I named Shape.

Window class should have getBiggest() and getSmallest() methods - first should return object which shape has biggest area (after computation) and second should return smallest.

All classes should have method which returns object's ID: obj.getId().

Circle and Rectangle classes should have methods:

- getPosition() which returns JSON with object position {x:?, y:?},
- getArea() which returns object's area,
- getRadius() which returns radius of object, made from Circle's class,
- getWidth() and getHeight() which returns width and height of object made from Rectangle class.

My code doesn't work as expected.

For example, when I run this code in Firefox, I get

> TypeError: win.getId is not a function _display:167

When clicked on _display:167 I get transferred to Developer's Tools Debugger which says

> {"error": "Please use POST request"}

When I comment out this huge console.log() and put

> console.log("winBiggest: " + winBiggest + "\nwinSmallest: " +
>   winSmallest);

instead, I get

```
"winBiggest: undefined       _display:167
winSmallest: undefined"
```

_display:167 also returns *{"error": "Please use POST request"}*.

What I made wrong here? I'm quite new to JS prototyping and inheritance - yesterday saw it on Codeschool course (JavaScript RoadTrip Part 3) for first time but only basics of it.

Thanks for eventual response and help.

Comment: `this.id` in `getId` doesn't exist on the `Shape` so `undefined` is correct.

Comment: But I've made `getId` an prototype of `Shape`.
Still don't get it..

Comment: Your code should be posted **here**, not on pastebin.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah, but I keep getting error that code should be formatted with 4 spaces to be posted, while it already IS formatted (used **{}** button). Also pasting url to JsFiddle or Codepen.io resulted in error, that such postings should be accompanied by code..
That's why I decided to use pastebin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`win` doesn't have the method `getId` because you've commented out the line that assigns the `Window` class its prototype.  It doesn't inherit from `Shape` at all.

When you do have it inherit properly, it is not going to do what you want anyway.  In the `Shape` constructor, you never assign to the `id` property, and you never reference the `newShapeObj` property in `getId`.

Keep that in mind in the rest of your constructors, where you also don't assign any properties that you reference later.  The `newShapeObj` means nothing to the interpreter, it has no reason to suspect that you want its properties to be copied to the new object.  If you want that behavior for all of your subclasses, you can add it to the `Shape` constructor:

```
function Shape(properties) {
    Object.keys(properties).forEach(function (propKey) {
        this[propKey] = properties[propKey];
    }, this);
}
```

but I wouldn't recommend it.  Instead, select the properties you want to assign to the object and get them from the initializing object:

```
function Shape(properties) {
    this.id = properties.id;
}
```

or dispose of the object altogether and pass the properties you want as parameters:

```
function Shape(id) {
     this.id = id;
}
```